# Reading JSON passed from javascript in php

Tags: javascript, php, json, post, decode

h have this JSON format in my controller:

```
$scope.my = {
        data: [
          {d1: '',d2: '',d3: ''},
        ]
      };
```

i'm passing it to php file as follows:

```
$http.post('file.php',{"json":$scope.my.data}).success(function(myData){});
```

in php file i used `json_decode` but everything is empty !!

i searched for this problem and i tried different solutions but nothing work, please any one can help ??? how i can read it ?!!

Update//
this what in my php file : $data =

```
json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); // this to recive the whole data
$rec_json=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data->json); // this to take the sent json
```

now how i can decode $rec_json ?!!

Comment: pass total json like: `{"json":$scope.my}`

Comment: Can you the code you use server side?  More than just the `json_decode`.  We need to see how you're reading from `$_POST` or wherever you're retrieving the string from.  This will help us help you better.  Just edit your question, and add the code there.

Comment: thanks, i tried this also ,, i think the big problem is when i try to decode json in the php file !! what is the best way to read the format in my question ?!!

Comment: Do `$array = json_decode($_POST['json']); if ( ! $array) { die(json_last_error()) }` it will tell you what went wrong.

Comment: Do you get the data in `file.php` file???

Comment: You have already array, so access it simple array accessing way.

Comment: what is the correct way ?? @FrayneKonok

Comment: The question is marked as duplicate so look at the duplicate question.